# Why can i add /page/674874 (or any number) to a URL and it still pulls up that page?

Tags: pagination

I have noticed that on any WordPress site you can add /page/7863/  (or any number) to any page url and it still shows that page and not a 404. Why is that? (Asking because my SEO company sends reports that show  /pages/(number)/  as different pages even though they are the same page just different number as shown in screenshot)

[image]

Comment: For SEO it should suffice to add a canonical URL. (Most SEO plugins should do that.) To try and answer: Because that is how pagination is setup in WordPress I think.

Comment: WP should add the canonical URL out of the box, it may be being removed, or your SEO tool may not be accounting for it